# Communication problem with MySql database, Laravel application hosted on Debian

Tags: mysql, laravel, debian

I have hosted a Laravel version 9 application on a Debian server, when I tried to do the migration from the command line, a driver problem was reported. I installed the PHP8-MySql driver and migrated successfully. When I tried to connect with the login route, the same driver problem was reported even though it was already installed

Illuminate\Database\QueryException could not find driver (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = admin@gmail.com limit 1)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have the php-mysql plugin installed properly. Reinstall by :

`sudo apt install php-mysql`

Also, it maybe possible that mysql is running in socket mode only. If that is the case, you need to find MySql's socket path. [This might help.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33378573/9184801)

Once you've found the socket path, you need to define the socket path on your .env file like this :

```
DB_SOCKET="/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"
```

Comment: I followed your instruction but it did not solve the problem 

MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'socket';
+---------------+-------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                   |
+---------------+-------------------------+
| socket        | /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock |
+---------------+-------------------------+

DB_SOCKET="/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"

Comment: did you make sure you have php-mysql installed?\

Comment: Yes, it's done, that's why I have then done the migration with php artisan migrate

Comment: go to public/index.php and put in

```
phpinfo();
die();
```

This should give you all the plugins you have. Make sure you see mysqli there. 

Sometimes, depending on your configuration, you may have different modules for web and cli

Comment: The first time I had the driver problem was when I wanted to do the migrations from the command prompt. I took care to install PHP8-MYSQL which is advised for the use of PHP8. After the installation my migrations went through without problem.

Comment: are you running the server with php8 artisan serve? You might need to do that. Also, if you're running it via apache2 or nginx, you might need to change php-fpm socket path

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, the definition of the path of the socket on the .env file had solved the problem, I had to restart the server so that it takes into account my modifications.

I think that answer can be voted as a good answer